# How do I dynamically edit the html and css of a website that is NOT mine using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to make a script that highlights certain divs/creates new divs on chess.com, a widely used website; this will be used to highlight moves that are suggested by an engine I will be making. I am really wondering how I'm supposed to get the website to read a .js file from my personal computer. I am aware this is quite an open ended question, so I am expecting open ended answers.

Comment: You'd have to create a browser extension. You cannot "tell" a random website to do something it's not programmed to do.

Comment: You can also use an existing extension, I personally use [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)

Comment: Check out [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) on Chrome.

Comment: StackOverflow is not designed for open ended questions. But what others have said: Write an extension/plugin or use an existing one